# How can i create register manage acount?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am new in SharePoint.I am trying to create register managed account for administrator but when I create register manage to account for administrator, it's say 
[image]

> The password for the WIN2012SVR\Administrator account has expired.
>   Update it and try again.

How can I update administrator account password?

Answer (score 2):

This error is indicating that the ACCOUNT has an expired password. Have you updated the credentials for the account outside of SharePoint? Also, it appears that you are using a local account. Generally, you should use domain accounts for SharePoint, with local accounts you will be limited to a single machine.